# Running Django apps tests in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, automated-tests, pycharm

I am having a hard time trying to configure tests running in PyCharm.

I want to run tests for my custom django apps, so my configuration looks something like this:

[image: Django apps in options field]

It works okay mostly (tests run, succeed), though it doesn't let you re-run individual tests and re-run failed ones - it always runs all tests for specified applications (common and authorization).

The manual says I should put django application names in "Target" field like this:

[image: Django apps in Target field]

But whenever I do it, my tests fail to run with weird errors: sometimes it cannot import some modules, though they are definitely accessible, sometimes there are a lot of NoReverseFound exceptions, though none of them are actually present in the code.

I suppose I am configuring something wrong, but I cannot understand what. I am running the latest version of PyCharm and one of the 1.5.x versions of Django (some legacy code from back in the day I had to maintain)

**UPD**: If I put `authorization.UserApiTestCase.test_login` in target - it works great, `authorization.UserApiTestCase` works too, but putting just appname (`authorization`) won't work and will produce NoReversrMatch or import errors... leaving Target empty will work, too, though it will run even iinternal Django tests and that's not what I need - I just want to run all my apps' tests (or tests from specific apps).

Comment: It would be nice if you mentioned Django version you use, since it has changed app loading and test handling in the last three versions.

Comment: 1st and 2nd pictures are the same.

Comment: No, they are not. Look at the Target and Options fields.

Comment: @IhorKaharlichenko as I mentioned above, it's 1.5.x :)

Comment: Are you sure that second screenshot is not what you want? It seems to work fine here.

Comment: @borfast it does not work for me - it throws either NoReverseMatch Exceptions or Import exceptions for me. Seems that if you run tests this way PyCharm will import thing differently than django does when you run manage.py test common authorization

Comment: @DataGreed, have you tried starting a project from scratch and running the tests there, just to rule off the possibility that it's something messed up in that specific project?

Comment: Can you post your test_settings?

Comment: @borfast well, i've tried setting up the same project from scratch - same thing.

Comment: @Chrismit test_setting contain different credentials for databases and cahces, they also feature a * import from common settings at the start of file, nothing more

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea, then. Sorry :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, it's a bug related to older versions of Django. Upgrading to latest (1.9.2 at the moment) resolved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If your project structure in PyCharm looks similar to this:

```
myproject
├── README.md
├── myproject
│   ├── app1
│   │   └── test.py
│   ├── app2
│   │   └── test.py
│   ├── app3
│   │   └── test.py
│   └── settings.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Then you may need to add the second level `myproject` folder as a ["Sources Root"](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html)

"Sources Root" folders are indicated by a blue folder icon in the "Project" window

To add a "Sources Root" go to Preferences -> Project:MyProject -> Project Structure

Also check off "add source roots to PYTHONPATH" in the "Run/Debug Configurations".

After that you should be able to run tests with specified targets.

Comment: My second-level older is already checked as source folder, though I don't have files named test.py, mine are named tests.py (django convention, i believe). "add source roots to PYTHONPATH" is set to true (has a tick in it)

Comment: my `managed.py` lives at the same level as `requirements.txt`. and `test.py` is a typo, you are correct, `tests.py` is the convention.

Comment: Well, unfortunately that didn't help :(